# Couldn't load plugin sextantelwgeomprovider, QGIS 2.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: qgis, python, sextante

I'm getting this error message when I start QGIS

> Couldn't load plugin sextantelwgeomprovider due an error when calling its classFactory() method
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 204, in startPlugin
>       plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
>     File "/home/sara/.qgis2/python/plugins/sextantelwgeomprovider/**init**.py", line 50, in classFactory
>       from sextantelwgeomprovider.SextanteLwgeomProviderPlugin import SextanteLwgeomProviderPlugin
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 453, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>     File "/home/sara/.qgis2/python/plugins/sextantelwgeomprovider/SextanteLwgeomProviderPlugin.py", line 28, in 
>       from sextante.core.Sextante import Sextante
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 453, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>   ImportError: No module named sextante.core.Sextante
>   Python version:
>   2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:01:27) 
>   [GCC 4.8.2]

QGIS version:

> 2.0.1-Dufour Dufour, exported

Python path:

> ['/usr/share/qgis/python', '/home/sara/.qgis2/python', '/home/sara/.qgis2/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']

Because of that I can't use any geoalgorithms. Is there a way of solving the bug: "No module named sextante.core.Sextante"?

I tried to fix it by using Plugin > Manage and Install Plugins... but I still receive and error message "The plugin requires a missing module sextante.core.Sextante". How can I install this module?

Comment: I think your QGIS version and therefore your processing plugin is completely outdated. Consider updating to at least QGIS 2.8